# JPA named query gets turned into incorrect SQL

Tags: jpa, jpql

I am building a JSF application and want to list some entities on a page. I three entities: `Panel`, `PanelDefinition` and `Protein`. One page is a kind of details page for one `Protein` entity. One thing I want to do on that details page is to list all `Panel` entities for that `Protein`.

To do this I use a method in my `PanelController` class (JSF managed session scoped bean), which use my `PanelService` (stateless EJB) to call the named query `Panel.byProtein`. When I do this I get the error:

```
Internal Exception: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '.panel_id) AND (t0.target = 5)) AND (t0.panel = t1.panel_id))' at line 1
Error Code: 1064
Call: SELECT t1.panel_id, t1.comment, t1.insert_date, t1.name, t1.panel_version, t1.status, t1.inserted_by, t1.previous_version FROM panel_definition t0, panel t1 WHERE (((t0.panel = t1.panel_id.t1.panel_id) AND (t0.target = ?)) AND (t0.panel = t1.panel_id))
    bind => [1 parameter bound]
Query: ReadAllQuery(name="Panel.byProtein" referenceClass=Panel sql="SELECT t1.panel_id, t1.comment, t1.insert_date, t1.name, t1.panel_version, t1.status, t1.inserted_by, t1.previous_version FROM panel_definition t0, panel t1 WHERE (((t0.panel = t1.panel_id.t1.panel_id) AND (t0.target = ?)) AND (t0.panel = t1.panel_id))")
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:679)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1995)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ServerSession.executeCall(ServerSession.java:570)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:299)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:694)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRowsFromTable(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2714)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.ExpressionQueryMechanism.selectAllRows(ExpressionQueryMechanism.java:2667)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.executeObjectLevelReadQuery(ReadAllQuery.java:477)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1155)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.execute(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1114)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ReadAllQuery.execute(ReadAllQuery.java:402)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.ObjectLevelReadQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(ObjectLevelReadQuery.java:1202)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2894)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1797)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1779)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1744)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeReadQuery(QueryImpl.java:258)
```

And `t0.panel = t1.panel_id.t1.panel_id` does indeed not look proper. How and why do I get incorrect sql?

Here are a simplified version of my entity classes:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Panel.findAll", query = "SELECT p FROM Panel p"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "Panel.byProtein", query = "SELECT p FROM Panel p JOIN p.panelDefinition pd WHERE pd.pdId = p.panId AND pd.protein.ID = :pid"),
})
public Class Panel {
    @Id
    private Integer panId;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "panel")
    private List<PanelDefinition> panelDefinition;
    //More attributes + getters and setter
}

@Entity
public Class PanelDefinition {
    @Id
    private Integer pdId;
    @JoinColumn(name = "protein", referencedColumnName = "ID")
    @ManyToOne
    private Protein protein;
    @JoinColumn(name = "panel", referencedColumnName = "panId")
    @ManyToOne
    private Panel panel;
    //More attributes + getters and setter
}

@Entity
public Class Protein {
    @Id
    private Integer ID;
    //More attributes + getters and setter
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I needed another `JOIN` in the query. This change fixed it:

Original:

```
SELECT p FROM Panel p JOIN p.panelDefinition pd 
WHERE pd.pdId = p.panId AND pd.protein.ID = :pid
```

Updated query:

```
SELECT p FROM Panel p JOIN p.panelDefinition pd 
JOIN pd.protein t 
WHERE p.panId = pd.panel.panId AND t.ID = :id
```